# How to keep Google Apps Script Secret?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to keep your GAS code a secret? I'm needing to keep some code in a spreadsheet secret.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can make your script separate from the spreadsheet. Then import it as a library. I believe that keeps your code private.

Just as a note, it seems that anyone with edit access to a spreadsheet also has edit access to the script associated with the spreadsheet.

Comment: there are occaisions when debug will break into a Library function - particularly if the Library includes try / catch pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via a share, but it is not easy. Share the document with another account, the other account is then able to access the spreadsheet. You can trigger the script in the other account via a URL. I have done this before, it does work.